# Develop an SSIS Custom Component with two sources and one target

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I'm developing my first SSIS Custom Component and I need it to have two sources and one output, but when I deploy the component, it turns out that I double click it and the "Advanced Editor" doesn't shows up, so I cannot add columns to my output.
I think that the problem might be the way that I'm adding my input columns. I'm creating my columns within the "ProvideComponentProperties()" method. Is it the right method?
Here's some of my code

```
       public override void ProvideComponentProperties()
        {
            this.ComponentMetaData.UsesDispositions = true;

            // Input data flow 0
            var input0 = this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New();
            input0.Name = "Input 0";
            input0.Description = "Input 0 description";
            input0.HasSideEffects = false;
            input0.ErrorRowDisposition = DTSRowDisposition.RD_RedirectRow;
            input0.ErrorOrTruncationOperation = "ValidationFailure";

            // Input data flow 1
            var input1 = this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New();
            input1.Name = "Input 1";
            input1.Description = "Input 1 description";
            input1.HasSideEffects = false; 
            input1.ErrorRowDisposition = DTSRowDisposition.RD_RedirectRow;
            input1.ErrorOrTruncationOperation = "ValidationFailure";

            // Async output
            var output1 = this.ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.New();
            output1.Name = "Output";
            output1.Description = "My output";
            output1.HasSideEffects = false;
            output1.SynchronousInputID = 0;
            output1.ExclusionGroup = 0;

            var col1 = ComponentMetaData.CustomPropertyCollection.New();
            col1.Name = "My custom property 1";
            var col2 = ComponentMetaData.CustomPropertyCollection.New();
            col2.Name = "My custom property 2";
        }
```

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 and .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0):

In your DtsPipelineComponentAttribute, set the NoEditor to False in order to have access to the advanced editor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.dtspipelinecomponentattribute.noeditor?#Microsoft_SqlServer_Dts_Pipeline_DtsPipelineComponentAttribute_NoEditor